# MongoDB not insert in order with PHP Driver

Tags: php, mongodb

There is a problem in inserting to MongoDB database. It is not insert to database in right order.

We read the writing concern in MongoDB:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php

We use mongoDB 2.6 and PHP driver 1.6 with following sample code:

```
set_message_sample('1');
set_message_sample('2');

set_message_sample($id) {
$connecting_string = sprintf('mongodb://%s:%d/%s', $hosts, $port,$database), // fill with right connection setting
$connection=  new Mongo($connecting_string,array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password)); // fill with proper authentication setting

$dbname = $connection->selectDB('dbname');

$collection = $dbname->selectCollection('collection');
$post = array(
    'title' => $id,
    'content' => 'test ' . $id,
);
$posts->insert($insert,array("w" => "1"));
```

Sometimes the result is inserting "2" before "1" to database. We want to inserting in right order (first "1" and next "2") all the times. I also notice that we order the collection with mongoID which automatically set by mongoDB.

We check many options but the problem not solved. How we could solve it? (  How we could disable something like cache or isolate the insert queue to MongoDB.)

Comment: post  your code and error.

Comment: Items within a collection do not have an inherent "order". You can order items when you query for them. Why/how do you think your items are in the "wrong order"?!

Comment: we order the collection with MongoID

Answer (score 0):

So, i think you could insert the second only after the confirmation of the first one. since the insert is asynchronous, you can't be sure who goes first. So you must insert only after the confirmation of the first one.